# How to type this Maybe functor?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, functor, option-type

This is my attempt to type a Maybe functor (the implementation is an adaptation from Dr. Frisby's):

```js
interface Maybe<T> {
  isNothing: () => boolean;
  map: <S>(fn: (x: T) => S) => T extends null | undefined ?  Maybe<S> : Maybe<T>;
  join: <S>(fn: (x: T) => S) => T | S;
  chain: <S>(fn: (x: T) => S) => T | S;
}

function Maybe<T>(x): Maybe<T> {
  const instance = {};

  const isNothing = () => x === null || x === undefined;
  const map = <S>(fn: (x: T) => S): T extends null | undefined ? Maybe<S> : Maybe<T> => isNothing() ? Maybe<T>(x) : Maybe<S>(fn(x));
  const join = () => isNothing() ? Maybe<T>(x) : x;
  const chain = <S>(fn: (x: T) => S) => (instance as Maybe<T>).map(fn).join();

  return Object.assign(instance, { isNothing, map, join, chain });
}
```

In the map I get this error:

```
Type 'Maybe<T> | Maybe<S>' is not assignable to type 'T extends null ? Maybe<S> : Maybe<T>'.
  Type 'Maybe<T>' is not assignable to type 'T extends null ? Maybe<S> : Maybe<T>'.
```

In the join I get this:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '(<S>(fn: (x: T) => S) => T | S) | (<S>(fn: (x: S) => S) => S | S)' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

Help me understand these errors and point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you pare this down into a [mcve]?  There seems to be lots of stuff going on here, only some of which you're asking about.  I see that your `join()` method is declared to take a callback parameter but in your implementation you're not passing a parameter.  Why are you rolling an object with `Object.assign()` and using arrow functions instead of using a `class`?  Why are you using `(instance as Maybe<T>).map` instead of just `map`?  Why does `chain()` have the same signature as `join()` but a quite different implementation?  I think it would help if you streamline your question. Good luck!

Comment: I'd be moving [this way](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYGwhgzhAECyYE8BGBTAPAFWigHgFxQDsATGAbwF8A+aMgWAChppiBXALlukIHs8ALAJaEA5pzwAnVigA00AG5gQ0zoVYgQ0AD7RWJFADNhKYtArauvAcLHQDSiLIVKV0LBQDcjZsB6EIkqzAeDwSABSKyiicWDpqGhZ6xIbGxACUtN7M0NYQAHRs0AC80BEuKMUl8SAZAPyWfEKi4lJOka7tFeacZNyNNpz2II5ynZydZl5MZlmCEABy-aJhaZxIPDwgKGCEmdPMEih4rBK7uQWseVZNIlPMFFkAtmAADmgAylRhBoScYTgxDJFGjvVZwRCoD40ej7aCHY6nHJCfJsK5LETQeqEFAAd3ByHQnzC51RnQyqlx+NQ30IxORFzyZLSWQe0wAVjxhGgAKpfXKceAEtCCyG8qhgkXoXl7bJwo4nM701HXGyY7iUyU8vlKy5k6B-Em68ppO4zabAfhgLlEn5-AFuIE0TWfCUQwnQrIHeWI87PF40tJ5DnCFam1ms7xAA) myself

Answer (score 0):

This is all wrong:

```
map: <S>(fn: (x: T) => S) => T extends null | undefined ?  Maybe<S> : Maybe<T>;
```

I think what you meant was

```
map: <S>(fn: (x: T) => S) => T extends null | undefined ?  Maybe<T> : Maybe<S>;
```

because the whole point of maybe is to stop computation if T extends null | undefined. either way, what your doing is asking typescript to compute whether or not a maybe instance is nothing before the program is executed. This is not the point of using maybe and brings no advantage. Id recommend writing a type Maybe that expresses the presence of a type A or the presence of the null type separately from your type for map

example implementation:

```
type Some<A> = { _tag: 'some', val: A };
type None = { _tag: 'none' };
// this is the lazy way to express T extends null | undefined ?  Maybe<T> : Maybe<S>;
// we dont care about computing it while writing a program, only that the program handles
// the none type
export type Maybe<A> = Some<A> | None;

const Some = <A>(a): Maybe<A> => ({ _tag: 'some', val: a });
const None = <A = unknown>(): Maybe<A> => ({ _tag: 'none' });

const isNone = <A = unknown>(fa: Maybe<A>) => fa._tag === 'none';

// (f) => (fa) => (fb)
const map = <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B, fa: Maybe<A>): Maybe<B> =>
    fa._tag === 'none' ? None() : Some(f(fa.val));

const chain = <A, B>(f: (a: A) => Maybe<B>, fa: Maybe<A>): Maybe<B> =>
    fa._tag === 'none' ? None() : f(fa.val);

export const Maybe = {
    Some,
    None,
    isNone,
    map,
    chain,
};
```